# Post request with AFNetworking

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking

I am newbie in programming, especially in network side. So now I'm creating app to interact with Instagram. In my project I use AFNetworking. I saw their documentation and many examples here. And I don't understand yet how to get POST request to Instagram API. Please could u give me the real code example or something where I can read about how to do this operation? Please help. I tried to make request like this, it gives no errors and no response. It gives nothing :(

```
(IBAction)doRequest:(id)sender{

NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.instagram.com/"];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
[httpClient defaultValueForHeader:@"Accept"];

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        user_token, @"access_token",
                        nil];

[httpClient postPath:@"/feed" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // reponseObject will hold the data returned by the server.
    NSLog(@"data: %@", responseObject);
}failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error retrieving data: %@", error);
}];


NSLog(@"click!!");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

few things to care about. 
Instagram API returns JSON so you can use AFJSONRequestOperation which will return an already parsed NSDictionary.
The Instagram API says that:

> All endpoints are only accessible via https and are located at
>   api.instagram.com.

You should make a change to your baseURL.

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:yourURL];
NSURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                             path:@"/your/path"
                                       parameters:yourParamsDictionary];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
[AFJSONRequestOperation
 JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request
 success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
{
    // Do something with JSON
}
 failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON)
{
    // 
}];

// you can either start your operation like this 
[operation start];

// or enqueue it in the client default operations queue.
[client enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, florian! I'll try it when I will be near my mac. One more thing: in request parameter "path" -- is it path to json or local path on the device?

Comment: It is the path to append to the base URL you provide to the AFHTTPClient. For example by specifying "/users/self/feed" for the path, the request URL will be `https://api.instagram.com/users/self/feed`.